# Serial port handshake. What the difference between Hardware and None handshaking?

Tags: serial-port, handshake

I'm trying to determine the difference when I open **serial port** with **hardware handshake** and **none handshake**.

It seems that in both cases I have to control `RTS/CTS` signals (just tested it with one COM device). 
So what the difference between opening serial port with hardware handshake and without handshaking?

From my previous understanding, when we work `without handshaking`, we don't care about `RTS/CTS` and `DTR/DSR` signals. Just send and receive data whenever we want. Was I wrong?

One more question. Can we work `without handshaking` in `full duplex` mode only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you probably know, the issue is "flow control".  Like the Clash song "Should I stay or should I go?".

RTS/CTS is hardware control.  XON/XOFF is software control.  Otherwise, "just keep going".

This link might explain further:

http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-232_flow_control.html

I suspect that when you were asking about "handshaking" with respect to "duplex", perhaps you meant this:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232
>
> In older versions of the specification, RS-232's use of the RTS and
>   CTS lines is asymmetric: The DTE asserts RTS to indicate a desire to
>   transmit to the DCE, and the DCE asserts CTS in response to grant
>   permission. This allows for half-duplex modems that disable their
>   transmitters when not required, and must transmit a synchronization
>   preamble to the receiver when they are re-enabled.

'Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4.
But I'm trying to find the difference in terms of operating by `RTS/CTS` signals:  
  
- Should I set/check `RTS/CTS` signals if I open serial port without `flow control`? Should I do these things manually if I open serial port with `hardware flow control`?  
  
- Can I set `RTS to High` after opening the port and don't touch it after that? Is it good practice?  
  
- In half duplex mode how can I change `CTS` signal to prevent data receiving? It seems I can set `RTS` and `DTR` signals and just check `CTS` and `DSR` signals.

Comment: @paulsm4 It's been 10 years but this link is really useful. Thanks! I'm currently implementing this dinosaur technology

Answer (score 1):

The difference is more about whether the kernel will pay attention to the `CTS`/`RTS` lines when deciding whether to send more data or not. With hardware handshaking turned on, it will. With it set to none, it won't, even though the `CTS`/`RTS` lines may stay asserted, so that the peer will know it can send data.